# how to assign user input to a variable in jenkinis UI

Tags: jenkins, interactive

in my pipe line i want to get the user input as a variable(the box in yellow.  [jenkins build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmXvZ.png)

my code looks like that:  [this is how the code looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gjz9.jpg)
What do i need to add to the code so i can assign the user input to a variable?
thanks

Comment: Please do not post code a a link, especially not as a link to an image. Instead, include all code which is relevant to the question in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parameterised build plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

where you can add

[image]

and use it within your build script:

[image]